# Who did Amasawa-san go see in the hospital?

Tags: dennou-coil

As we find out at the end of the series…

> Amasawa Yuuko's brother actually died in an accident some years ago and was not in a coma like she thought.

So who did she go visit in the hospital then? Was it a very complicated hologram and she's never taken her glasses off the entire time (hard to believe, but not impossible)? Or was it another person in disguise hired by the Megamass?